# changing <span> to <p> through DOM

Tags: jquery

I am receiving a piece of HTML code from a plugin and I want to change all instances of `<span class="post-stats">` to `<p class="post-stats">` in the code. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: search replace with your editor?

Comment: sorry maybe i'm wording it wrong. the code is generated by a plugin and i want to change it through the dom. if my wording is wrong, please forgive me. i'm still a beginner.

Comment: @Miquel: Through the DOM. Runtime, client side, that is.

Comment: Search replace the code of the plugin then?

Comment: @Haochi i'd rather not change the code of the plugin since when i update it, all will be lost.

Comment: Ok gotcha, I did not understand initially

Comment: @J82: Try to alter the behaviour of them tags instead, cause I don't think you can change the element's type. But you can control their behaviour through CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `replaceWith()` would work?

```
$('span.post-status').replaceWith(function()
{
  return '<p class="post-stats">' + $(this).html() + '</p>';
});
```

---

Instead of doing all this stuff, why not just make the `<span>` act like a `<p>` with CSS? Adding this to your stylesheet should suffice.

```
span.post-status
{
  display: block;
}
```

Or, if you insist on jQuery:

```
$('span.post-status').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: sorry, but not making much sense to me here

Comment: Whoops. I forgot to replace it!

Comment: Yeah, I think css would be the better option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var spanPostStats = $( 'span.post-stats' );
spanPostStats.replaceWith(
    $( '<p>' ).addClass( 'post-stats' ).html( spanPostStats.html() )
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/nEJG2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.post-stats').each(function(i,elem){
    $(elem).replaceWith('<p class="post-stats">'+$(elem).html()+'</p>');
});
```

[**Here's an example ࢐**](http://jsfiddle.net/XfhjB/2/)

Comment: That may get the job done, but is inefficient compared to other verions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for [`.replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)?

```
$('span.post-stats').replaceWith(function(){
  return $('<p>').addClass('post-stats').html($(this).contents());
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/EMRTj/1/)**

*I know I'm a little late, but not a fan of using the `.each` or `.html(.html())` method(s). I also think you should use `.text()` or `.addClass` whenever possible keeping HTML markup where it belongs, and leave javascript to manipulating the propert(y/ies).*

Comment: Thanks, except `p` and `<span>` should be switched. ;)

Comment: Nice work. My only issue with your answer is that it requires 3 separate calls to the jQuery factory.

Comment: @JAAulde: What do you think passing it an HTML string is doing? jQuery's just calling `.attr` behind the scenes. ;p

Comment: I'm not talking about your call to addClass. I recognize that your using addClass is actually more efficient than my using an attr in the markup (My JSFiddle uses addClass, I'll edit that in my post here). I am talking about the three calls to $() you have--one for the span search, one for the p creation, and one to recapture the span as 'this'.

Comment: @JAAulde: Broken down we both have the same amount of work going on, less the overhead of a variable (trivial, but existent).  I guess I'm just confused how you perceived it as an _issue_. Either way, the OP got his/her answer, and everyone goes home happy. ;-)

Comment: Sorry for using the word issue. It's a nitpick, I'm an idiot. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery, look at the following function:
http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/